# Importing Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I am not able to import tensorflow. I have uninstalled it and installed it again using `!pip install --user tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall` but then also its not getting imported. Below I have attached the error I am getting in importing tensorflow. I am also not able to use keras due to this issue because keras is using tensorflow backend.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 
     42 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot I found the problem and would like to share if someone face this issue then run your anaconda prompt as `administrator` and then use the command `pip install --user tensorflow --force-reinstall`